# How to enable SNMP on Linksys WAG120N

Tags: snmp

I'm trying to enable SNMP on my [WAG120N](http://www.linksys.com/in/support-product?pid=01t80000003prsQAAQ).
There is no config for enabling such a feature in device configuration page (`http://192.168.1.1`)
But when I back up my config and open it in a text editor there are SNMP configs:

```
snmp_enable=0
snmp_read_community=
snmp_set_community=
snmp_sys_name=
snmp_sys_contact=
snmp_sys_location=
snmp_trap_to=
```

How can I enable `SNMP` on Linksys `WAG120N`?

Comment: Can you log into the router using telnet?

Comment: Write in values, save and restore backup?

Comment: @Moses: I tried `telnet 192.168.1.1 23` but the port is not open. there isn't any config for telnet too!

Comment: @Divin3: yeah I thought of that but why the config is not available in config interface?

Comment: There is no telnet functionality for this device. There are some hidden settings that you can access here: `http://192.168.1.1/setup.cgi?next_file=adsl_driver​.htm`

or

`http://192.168.1.1/setup.cgi?todo=debug`

Comment: To revert from debug mode to normal mode again, you will have to switch off your router for a while , then switch on.

Comment: "but why the config is not available in config interface" Because SNMP is usually reserved for business-level models.  So it's probably in the configuration because they use the same OS between many models, but your model itself doesn't support SNMP -- either because it actually doesn't have the capability, or because they've crippled it on purpose.

Comment: @Divin3: the `http://192.168.1.1/setup.cgi?next_file=adsl_driver.htm` page only shows a log that i can download; it doesnt have any configuration feature; and the debug link just shows `DEBUG enable` text

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007: So I can't fill the fields in config backup and restore them to force it enable that?

Comment: My guess would be that it will simply ignore the settings, but yeah, that's what I'd try.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The presence of the `SNMP` settings in the backup doesn't mean that the router supports `SNMP`. It is possible that Linksys uses the same backup function for multiple routers and some of them does support `SNMP`.

I have also downloaded the manual and did not find anything about `SNMP` mentioned in it.

Also, according to [this](https://community.linksys.com/t5/Cable-and-DSL/Linksys-WAG120N-management/td-p/311962), the router lacks the telnet functionality.

> Re: Linksys WAG120N management
>
> .... ‎09-11-2010 12:06 PM
>
> hello OverCLK , dont you know that this product as well as the wag160n
>   and wag320n lacks telnet functionality ?

All You can do is hope that this will change in the future with a software update (I don't think this will happen). Or You can contact Linksys support for more information.